# Airport transit visa to Lisbon

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, moroccan-citizens, lis

I am a Moroccan citizen flying from Casablanca to New York via Lisbon (TAP Portugal). The layover is around 8 hours at Lisbon and I have no Schengen visa of any type.

Do I need an airport transit / transit visa for Lisbon?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=MA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=00&TR=PT&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day

So no, you do **not** need an airport transit visa